# I'm having a hard time interfacing Jasper Reports 6.2 Library with Netbeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: java

The project I'm working on uses MS SQL Server and I'm connecting to it using sqljdbc4.jar driver, which works fine.
Now when I add all the Jasper Report libraries to the project folder, the program loses the driver to the database and throws a runtime error that it cannot find the driver for sql server.

However, if I remove two library files (olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.jar and mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar) from the project library folder, the program is then able to recognize the sqljdbc4.jar driver and connect to the database. But the report does not get populated/printed with data from the database, it gives an error message saying:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

How can I solve this?